# Change custom UIView at run time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How should I change the custom view in viewController with different custom UIView class at run time? My code snippet looks like following but doesnt change the custom view.

```
class BaseView: UIView {

}

class view1: BaseView {

}

class view2: BaseView {

}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
   var customView: BaseView?

   init() {
      customView = view1()
   }

   @objc changeView() {
     customView = view2()
     self.customView.setNeedsDisplay()

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new custom view is not visible, cause you didn't add it to the view controller view hierarchy

Stack view adds this automatically when you call addArrangedSubview, but regular view do not

If you are using constraints then you should recreate this with code

try this

```
@objc func changeView() {
    let newView = view2()
    newView.frame = customView.frame
    customView.superview?.addSubview(newView)
    customView.removeFromSuperview()
    customView = newView

    self.customView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing old customView from parent View (in my case stack view) and adding new initialized custom view into stackView worked.